# Create .7z archive with custom header(Creating a .unity3d file)

Tags: compression, unity-game-engine

So, I recently came across the .unity3d file for a game a used to play, and unpacked it using a tool. (http://en.unity3d.netobf.com/) Now, I've made the tweaks the the game I needed to to make it run on a local server, and have come across the issue of how to compress the files back into a .unity3d file. I've reverse engineered the tool and determined that .unity3d files are LZMA compressed( just like a .7z archive ), but the header is "UnityWeb" instead of "7z". How might I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

7z is open source. If the only difference is indeed that header, then get [the sources](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sevenzip/files/7-Zip/), find where the header is, change it and compile your own compression utility. Watch out for other constants describing the headers and signatures though (e.g. length of the signature). I'd suggest starting with line 9 of the file Xz.c (defining `XZ_SIG` and `XZ_FOOTER_SIG`).